# How to add all the folders under `/lib` to "Additional Library Directories" in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio, build, linker

I have a folder path `/lib`. In it there is `/lib/A/a.lib`, `/lib/B/b.lib`, `/lib/C/c.lib`, ...`/lib/Z/z.lib`. When I just put `/lib` in "Additional Library Directories", the linker cannot find `a.lib, b.lib, ..., z.lib`. It seems the linker will just search '/lib'. So how to make the linker search all the folders under `/lib` to find the libraries? I just do not want to add the library path one by one.

Comment: You can't, you have to add the folders individually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you couldn't add all the folders under `/lib` to “Additional Library Directories”. You could only add the library path one by one.